# Как поставить многоточие в конце блока с текстом в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, текст, unity3d-ui

В поле текста вмещается 10 символов. А текст который нужно разместить в текстовом поле имеет длину 15+. Следовательно, надо вместить 7 символов и многоточие в конце(3 точки).

P.S.
Заранее определить кол-во символов в текстовом поле нельзя из-за зависимости от разрешения экрана

Comment: У TextMesh Pro есть опция Overflow, там нужно поставить Ellipsis, это делает в точности то, что вам нужно. Но с бубном поплясать все равно придется, потому что поля ввода в TextMesh Pro ***очень*** глючные и будут отображать многоточие прям во время ввода. Если использование TMP вам подходит, расскажу про настройку более подробно.

Comment: @trollingchar, имеются ли другие опции, кроме как использование TMP?

Comment: Теоретически, можно сделать с помощью комбинации Horizontal Layout Group и двух текстовых полей, при изменении текста найти скриптом Preferred Width текста и если она больше чем максимум то включить текст где три точки.

Comment: @trollingchar, пожалуй, про первый вариант я бы хотел услышать чуть поподробнее.

Comment: Приду домой, расскажу про оба.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## С помощью TextMesh PRO

Текст в TMP имеет опцию **Overflow - Ellipsis**, которая, если он залезет за края, обрежет его так, чтобы уместить три точки на конце, и отобразит их. Но подвох в том, что текстовое поле будет делать это прямо при вводе, и это вообще не хорошо. Поэтому нужно менять режим для текста, когда поле активно.

Для этого напишем такой класс:

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;


[RequireComponent (typeof (TMP_InputField))]
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private TMP_InputField _inputField;


    private void Awake () {
        _inputField = GetComponent <TMP_InputField> ();
        _inputField.textComponent.overflowMode = TextOverflowModes.Ellipsis;
        _inputField.onSelect  .AddListener (OnSelect);
        _inputField.onDeselect.AddListener (OnDeselect);
        _inputField.onEndEdit .AddListener (OnEndEdit);
    }


    private void OnDestroy () {
        _inputField.onEndEdit .RemoveListener (OnEndEdit);
        _inputField.onDeselect.RemoveListener (OnDeselect);
        _inputField.onSelect  .RemoveListener (OnSelect);
    }


    private void OnSelect (string _) {
        _inputField.textComponent.overflowMode = TextOverflowModes.Overflow;
    }


    private void OnDeselect (string _) {
        _inputField.textComponent.overflowMode = TextOverflowModes.Ellipsis;
    }


    private void OnEndEdit (string _) {
        var eventSystem = EventSystem.current;
        if (!eventSystem.alreadySelecting) eventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject (null);
    }

}
```

Суть такова: при выборе поля ввода текст станет обычным, который можно выделить весь и пролистать, а когда оно неактивно, текст станет опять обрезанным и с многоточием. Кидать компонент нужно на тот же объект, где висит TMP_InputField.

[Зачем здесь надо обрататывать onEndEdit (вопрос с ответом на английском SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145437/how-to-make-textmesh-pro-input-field-deselect-on-enter-key)

#### Внимание!

Крайне не рекомендуется ставить для текста выравнивание по любому краю, кроме левого. С этим связана целая куча багов, которые я до сих пор не все исправил, даже имея доступ к исходникам TextMesh PRO. Вероятно, его недостаточно тестировали в этих режимах. С левым выравниваем работает нормально.

Comment: Заставить работать обычный Input Field не удалось, даже наследуясь от него. Методы `OnSelect` и `OnDeselect` у него есть, но они вызываются не тогда, когда ожидалось. Кроме того, по какой-то причине объект с многоточием сохраняет выключенное состояние после режима Play.